# How to compile and run C program in sublime text 3 in windows 10?

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I installed mingw according to https://nuwen.net/mingw.html including running the set_distro_paths.bat. How do I compile and run in powershell? Also, how would I compile in sublime?

I remember doing something like adding the compiler to my system path with Java but I don't know exactly what to do with C or if it's needed after running the batch file. After this step, what do I have to do with the build system in ST or do I create a new build system? If I create a new one, what do I enter in the new file?

After creating a file called hello.c, I tried going into to the file location in powershell.
Typing cl hello.c or gcc hello.c both produced The term 'cl'/'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: have you tried using cygwin? I've built several C programs with cygwin (installing gcc in cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

set_distro_paths.bat is designed to be run *every time you want to use mingw programs.* In other words, you'd have to open powershell, run "set_distro_paths.bat," and *then* compile.

If you don't want to do that, you can add the installation location + "bin" to your system path.

I've created a list of instructions in case you don't know the process. It seems complicated, but it's really fairly easy.

1. Search "env" from the start menu.
2. Select "Edit environmental variables for your account." A window will open.
3. If there is no "PATH" option in the first list, click "New..." and enter "PATH" in the first text box and your installation location in the second. Click Ok. You're done!
4. Otherwise, highlight "PATH" in the first list.
5. Choose Edit.
6. If you see a window with a text box on it, add the path - and a trailing semicolon - to either the start or the end.
7. If you see a list of items, click New... and enter your installation location.
8. Click Ok to dismiss both dialog boxes.

Comment: So am I only changing user variable or user and system variable? Is the path for either one to MinGW or to MinGW\bin? After what is the command to compile and run?

Comment: The path is "MinGW/bin." The instructions just change the current user  variable - you can change the system variable, but I didn't want to go into too much detail. Your commands should work once the path is set.